# I can not push objects into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am have a problem that I am not able to push the object into the nested array. Please help thank you!

Here is my code:

```
let obList = [
    { date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 2055 },
    { date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 2053 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 1652 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 152 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 1562 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 2662 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 3652 }
];

let lit = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
let mainList = [[],[]]
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  obList.forEach(el=>{
    console.log(el.id >= 2000)
    if(obList.id >= 2000){
      mainList[i].push("ss")
    }
  })
}
console.log(mainList)
```

The output for the mainList is empty

```
[ [], [] ]
```

Comment: Not that this is the main issue, but consider using `filter` instead?

Comment: Your if condition is wrong,  you need to use el.id>=2000

Answer (score 2):

I guess the line `if(obList.id >= 2000){` should be `if(el.id >= 2000){` as `obList`doesn't have any id field.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `el.id` instead of `obList.id`.

`obList.id` is always undefined because it points to your array.